# how to make multiple checkbox required but with pure css no javascript

Tags: html, css

so i created a form with checkboxes and radio buttons but but i want them to be required to submit what is the approunch i should use. no javascript just css please.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked> Montly Subscription - $JMD 5,000. First time subscription is $JMD 3999.
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked> Annual Subscription - $JMD 55,000. First time subscription $JMD 50,999.
</label>
```

these are the radio buttons as well

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked> MasterCard
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio"> Visa
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked> Discover
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio"> Paypal
</label>
```

Comment: CSS will never prevent navigation to new page or form submits.

Comment: I'd simply use the attribute `required` where needed

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="optradio" required /> Paypal` - [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" required>
```

In this case the appropriate attribute would be `required` of `input` tag is used. This will make sure that the user checks the checkbox